# What address do I use to access my server from the internet?

Tags: security, ftp, webserver, self-hosting

I have an FTP server hosted on my computer and I want to make it publicly accessible.

I have forwarded the necessary ports for this specific computer on my router. If I type in my local ip, 192.168.x.x, i can access it. But this is only local. How do I access it publicly?

I tried going to my public ip but nothing comes up. I have searched Google for several hours now and have come up with nothing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test your server on https://incloak.com/ports/ or http://www.hackerwatch.org/probe/ sites and check that it detects your open FTP server. If not check you operating system firewall.

Comment: It is saying that my ports 80 and 21 are closed. How do I open them?

Comment: Either there is a problem about settings on your router (it is not redirecting port 21 to your computer) or your OS on computer is blocking connections on port 21.